# AD reset user passwords for a security group

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I'm not quite sure if this is possible or not, but I need to force a certain security group's users to have their passwords expire so they'll be forced to change them on next login. The reason for this is because I applied a FGPP (password policy) to this particular group in order to enforce strong passwords. Well, many users have really weak passwords and they won't be changed unless they're forced.

Is there a way to do this without forcing everyone to a single password?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this in Powershell and Set-ADUser.  Change the ChangepasswordatLogon flag to True.

Would look something like this:

```
Get-ADuser -Filter {memberof -RecursiveMatch "DN of Security Group"} | Set-ADuser -ChangePasswordatLogon:$true
```

Comment: I'd have to do this with each user, right? Suppose I can pull the list from the security group and loop it if I need to.

Comment: And as I post that it's edited with the filter :) i'll give it a try!

Comment: Yeah I updated it.  That should work for you.

Comment: I just tried it and get a syntax error. I put in the DN of the group I'm attempting to use.

Comment: What is the error message?  Did you put the DN in quotes if there are spaces in it?

Comment: "Syntax error at position 10" code is `Get-ADuser -Filter {memberof "CN=PasswordPolicyUsers,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=local"} | Set-ADuser samaccountname -ChangePasswordatLogon:$true`

Comment: Fixed in a chat convo. Updated your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer vbscript, even though why not use Powershell: A search for "vbscript set AD password to expired" yielded this article:
[How Can I Cause a User’s Password to Expire?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/07/06/how-can-i-cause-a-user-s-password-to-expire.aspx)

I haven't tested it personally. The sample vbscript code is:

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://CN=myerken,OU=Finance,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com")

objUser.pwdLastSet = 0
objUser.SetInfo
```

You can combine this with other code to get the list users from the security group (use the security group CN= in the LDAP query) and loop through them applying this password expiration. This is a good example of that found by searching "vbscript getobject security group":
[Get all users in specific AD group using VbScript](http://www.winfrastructure.net/article.aspx?BlogEntry=Get-all-users-in-specific-AD-group-using-VbScript)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Command Prompt option:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dsquery group -name "<INSERT_GROUP_NAME_HERE>" ^| dsget group -members -expand') do (
   dsmod user %a -mustchpwd yes
)
```

Comment: I'm so glad PowerShell now exists...